# using same kind of javascript in more than 1 divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating cube animations using javascript which is working fine but when i create another `div` with the same `id` of javascript then second `div` is not using dat same script. How do i do that? so i can use same scripts in more than one `divs`?

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Image Cube</title>
<style type="text/css">
#basicCube { width: 150px; height: 150px;}
#basicCube img{border:3px solid #ccc}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imagecube.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#basicCube').imagecube();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="basicCube">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="6.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a class instead `$('.basicCube').imagecube();`

Comment: It's because you have to make uqnique id for each element, you can make different selector like $('div') if you want it to appear for all divs at page, or you can make 1 call for class.

Comment: Use class instead of id

Comment: The div cannot use script, it's a div, it doesn't think. It's the script who use the div. And what happens when you have multiple divs with the same id?? only one will be recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use an identifier more than once in a document. In this case you will want to use classes instead:

#### CSS

```
.basicCube { width: 150px; height: 150px;}
.basicCube img{border:3px solid #ccc}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="basicCube">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="6.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
</div>
<div class="basicCube">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="6.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('.basicCube').imagecube();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('.basicCube').imagecube();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="basicCube">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="6.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `id` only one time. Use class there.

```
 <div class="basicCube">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
    <img src="6.jpg" alt="Gorge" title="Gorge">
</div>

$(function () {
    $('.basicCube').imagecube();
});
```